# Terminating Git

Tags: git

I accidentally typed git init in my home directory which caused git to start tracking everything in my home directory and I need to remove it.

Is there a git command or a way to terminate git tracking everything in my home directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git creates a folder `.git` in the top-level directory it tracks. The only thing you need to do is to remove that folder using `rm -Rf .git`.

Comment: Thanks a million Jan! Nothing complicated, just as I like it.

Comment: It's worth noting that without additional commands, `git init` won't track any changes—it will just save the state of the directory at the time `git init` was run.  If you later added and then deleted a file, `git` wouldn't know about that file.  (If privacy/security is a concern.)